# Retrieve Index When Passing Object to Function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I'm passing an Object from an array of objects to a function. Is it possible to still retrieve the index number somehow from the object in the function?
 I'm doing this in javaScript specifically within the controller of AngularJS.

For instance

```
var array= [
    {
        name: "name1"
    },
    {
        name: "name2"
    }
];

function( passedInObjectFromArray ) {
    return passedInObjectFromArray.indexVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do,

```
$scope.retrieveIndex =  function(passedInObjectFromArray){
    return array.indexOf(passedInObjectFromArray);
 }
```